# Use a batch file to change resolution and refresh rate for a specific program

Tags: batch-file, refresh, resolution, monitor

I want a batch or program that will open an application (the steam game csgo) change the computers resolution to **1280x960** (the res I play at) and "overclock" the monitor to **75Hz** then revert to normal when the application is closed.

I've looked for something to do this online and found 12noon's Display Changer. At first glance it says it will do everything I need, change my resolution and refresh rate then revert. However the how to section is not very user friendly (http://12noon.com/?page_id=80) and I can't find any tutorials online.

It tells me to change the programs shortcut to something like this -

```
dc.exe -width=640 -height=480 -depth=8 -refresh=72 "c:\Program Files\Hasbro\Freddi.exe"
```

So I try to change CSGO's shortcut to

```
dc.exe -width=1280 -height=960 -depth=32 -refresh=75 "steam://rungameid/730"
```

and as soon as I click apply it changes to a bing search for those terms. I feel like I'm making a really obvious newbie error but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks simple. As last parameter dc.exe requires the path to an exe file. Instead you are giving it steam://rungameid/730. This is not an executable but a command line extention for **steam**. You will have to find out how to start your game directly instead of using the steam-link.

Comment: Could be something like dc.exe -width=1280 -height=960 -depth=32 -refresh=75 "C:\Path\To\Steam.exe -applaunch 730". Can't check as I don't have steam. Obv you have to modify the path to fit your steam folder.

Comment: @MichaelS I'm able to get a shortcut that opens CSGO as normal (the way I tried to do it before would give me Steam errors) but now with the extra code in the shortcut it tells me dc.exe is not valid and wants me to make sure the path and file name are correct. Again I'm almost certain its an obvious mistake I'm making. The code I tried was - dc.exe -width=1280 -height=960 -depth=32 -refresh=70 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" -applaunch 730   starting in - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam"